# NullPointerException and couldn't initialize sketch errors in Processing

Tags: java, 2d, simulation, physics

I wrote a  physical simulation about gravitational force between two planets.It worked perfectly fine so I decided to take it to a new level and rewrote it using arrays and five planets(circles).But my code gives strange and never the same error. I get either NullPointerException error or the VM error when intializing the sketch(No description just the "Vm error couldn't initialize skecth" and the  "see help and troubleshoot" bullsh*t) The program uses a txt file to read in data(double-checked and it works fine).
My Array names and descriptions are

- PVector - Pos stands for Position
- PVector - Vel stands for Velocity
- PVector - Acc stands for Acceleration
- PVector - Dist stands for    Distance
- PVector - Dir stands for Direction
- float - Mass stands for    Mass

My code:

```
 public PVector[] Pos = new PVector[5];
public PVector[] Acc = new PVector[5];
public PVector[] Vel = new PVector[5];
public PVector[] Dist = new PVector[5];
public PVector[] Dir = new PVector[5];
public float[] Mass = new float[5];
void setup(){
 String Data[] = loadStrings("Data.txt");
 size(800,800);
 for(int g = 0;g < 5;g++){
   Pos[g] = new PVector(float(Data[g+1]),float(Data[g+6]));
   Vel[g] = new PVector(float(Data[g+12]),float(Data[g+17]));
   Mass[g] = float(Data[g+23]);
 }
}
void draw(){
 for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++){
   for (int f = 0;f < 5;f++){
     if(i !=f){
       if(Pos[i].x < Pos[f].x){Dir[f].x = 1;Dist[f].x = (Pos[f].x - Pos[i].x);}else{ // I get the error here
       if(Pos[i].x > Pos[f].x){Dir[f].x = -1;Dist[f].x = (Pos[i].x - Pos[f].x);}else{
       if(Pos[i].x == Pos[f].x){Dir[f].x = 0;Dist[f].x = 0;}}}
       if(Pos[i].y < Pos[f].y){Dir[f].y = 1;Dist[f].y = (Pos[f].y - Pos[i].y);}else{
       if(Pos[i].y > Pos[f].y){Dir[f].y = -1;Dist[f].y = (Pos[i].y - Pos[f].y);}else{
       if(Pos[i].y == Pos[f].y){Dir[f].y = 0;Dist[f].y = 0;}}}
       if ((Dist[f].x != 0)){
         Acc[i].x+=((6*((Mass[i]*Mass[f])/Dist[f].magSq())/10000000)/Mass[i])*Dir[f].x;// *6/1000000 is MY G constant
       }
       if ((Dist[f].y != 0)){
         Acc[i].y+=((6*((Mass[i]*Mass[f])/Dist[f].magSq())/10000000)/Mass[i])*Dir[f].y;
       }
     }
   }
   Vel[i].x = Vel[i].x + Acc[i].x;
   Vel[i].y = Vel[i].y + Acc[i].y;
   Pos[i].x = Pos[i].x + Vel[i].x;
   Pos[i].y = Pos[i].y + Vel[i].y;
   ellipse(Pos[i].x,Pos[i].y,10,10);
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok my Data.txt contains:"Pos: 10 60 110 160 210 10 60 110 160 210 Vel: 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Mass: 1 1 1 1 1" All spaces are new lines! I hope I gave all the information needed to help me out.

Comment: on which line you get NullPointerException? Why you dont insert stack trace of these errors?

Comment: @KickButtowski What info do you need exactly?

Comment: @libik The code has coments in it concerning where do i get the error

Comment: @Sipi you got your answer already kind of but I still say your code is not indented and so not readable at all.

Comment: Dear @KickButtowski ,I still don't get what is unreadable in my code.

Comment: @Sipi look how to indent your code for more readability

Comment: Sorry @KickButtowski but I still don't get what you are talking about

Comment: Please, do not put `ANSWERED` in your question's title. Since you've marked one of the answers as accepted, the Stack Overflow system already shows the question as answered by setting the foreground colour in the "X answers" field to yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create array of PVectors of size 5 here : `public PVector[] Dir = new PVector[5];` . In this moment, it has `null` five times for indexes 0-4 in it.

Because you do not create new PVectors in this array, when you try to access variable x in here `Dir[f].x`, you got error, because `Dir[f]` is null and you cant access variable `x` of `null` -> NullPointerException.

In this part you are instantizing some arrays

```
for(int g = 0;g < 5;g++){
   Pos[g] = new PVector(float(Data[g+1]),float(Data[g+6]));
   Vel[g] = new PVector(float(Data[g+12]),float(Data[g+17]));
   Mass[g] = float(Data[g+23]);
 }
```

You should add instantizing also for `Dir`, `Acc` and `Dist`

---

Note also, that you are working with objects, not with primitive data types. `null` is not same as `new PVector(0,0)`

---

Also from "design" point of view, using arrays this way is NOT good approach. You should create your own class `Planet`, where each planet holds information about its properties and in your main class you handle interaction between them.

---

How to create "empty" or "zero" variables instead of nulls? Just create them :)

```
for(int g = 0;g < 5;g++){
   Pos[g] = new PVector(float(Data[g+1]),float(Data[g+6]));
   Vel[g] = new PVector(float(Data[g+12]),float(Data[g+17]));
   Mass[g] = float(Data[g+23]);
   Dir[g] = new PVector(0,0);
   Acc[g] = new PVector(0,0);
   Dist[g] = new PVector(0,0);
 }
```

PS : I do not how exactly is this class implemented, using `new PVector()` or `new PVector(0)` instead of `new PVector(0,0)` may also work.

Comment: Well @libik this seems to be the right answer but what if I want Dir Acc and Dist to be (0,0)?

Comment: @libik I saw yur edit and I agree but I'm a bit of a newbie and I dont really know how to create and use classes(my own) but thanks for the tip!